# howt to shoutcast streaming on Android

Tags: android, shoutcast

Is there a way to stream shoutcast on the android? my shoutcast ip : 188.247.86.66 port 8002

can someone give me a code to an app for stream shoutcast?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is only possible in Android version 2.2 and above.. you can natively stream to shoutcast.